# How to make an SKSprite node move side to side on its own when game starts?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making a swift game with spritekit where I just added an image to the scene that's an SKSpriteNode. When the game starts, I want to make it move just on the x-axis from the left side of the screen to the right side, repeating forever. I'm struggling with what the code should be for this.

The code for my image is:

```
func addDrake1(){
    let Drake1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Drake1")
    Drake1.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, y:self.frame.size.height - 300)
    Drake1.zPosition = 2
    addChild(Drake1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you start your sprite position from the far left at cgpoint(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - 300)

you could use this method :

```
func moveSprite() {

        let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 2)

        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 2)


        let moveBackAndForth = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveRight, moveLeft]))


        Drake1.runAction(moveBackAndForth)

     }
```

you could also change the speed at which the sprite moves by changing the duration in the actions moveLeft and moveRight

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I added that code into my addDrake1 function and he still did not move.

Comment: hmm.. i tried it myself and it worked. you should make your sprite an instance of the class by moving this line :    let Drake1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Drake1") above didMoveToView. also, don't forget to call the function moveSprite() inside of didMoveToView.

Comment: I just had to remove the "func movesprite" part and it worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: @NickyNick321 - Daniel had provided the moving code as a function to be called via moveSprite() It keeps your code cleaner and, with a little modification, you could also pass it the name of a sprite so that any sprite could be set to moving in the same way.